# SuiteCrm Email Notifications Duplicating

Tags: email, suitecrm

I have created a module in suitecrm that would allow users to create or view nc case. When a nc case is created an email notification is sent to the person assigned to this variable $rev_email, however when the email is sent it is being duplicated in the person's inbox when the admin should only be receiving it once.

```
function createCaseEmail(&$email,$rev_email,$subject,$bean,$xtpl){
        /* Set Email Subject */
        $email->Subject=$subject;

    /* Get NC Case Number */
    $case_number = $bean ->case_number;
    $xtpl->assign('Case_Number', $case_number );

    /* Get NC Subject */
    $xtpl->assign('Case_Subject', $bean->name);

    /* Get Case Description */
    $xtpl->assign('Case_Desc', $bean->description_c);



    /* Create email message using email template and data above */
    $xtpl->parse('main');               
    $email->Body = from_html($xtpl->text('main'));


    return $email;
}
class cases_email_notification
{
function send_notification($bean, $event, $arguments)
{

    /*Get sugar email engine*/

    $email = new SugarPHPMailer();
    $email->From = 'it@gmail.com';
    $email->FromName ='SuiteCRM';

    $rev_email = 'admin@gmail.com';

    /* Get sugar template engine */
    $xtpl = new XTemplate("XTemplate/CasesEmailTemplate.html");

        /*GEt the URL for the NC Case */
        $url =  $GLOBALS['sugar_config']['site_url'].'index.php?module=Cases&action=DetailView&record='.$bean->id; 
        $xtpl -> assign('URL', $url);


        /* Get Case ID */
        $id = $bean->getFieldValue('id');

        if(empty($bean->fetched_row['id'])){

            $email=createCaseEmail($email,$rev_email,'New Case Email Notification',$bean,$xtpl);                

            /* Send email to Production Department */
            $email->addAddress($rev_email);
        }
        //Send email
        $email->isHTML(true);
        $email->prepForOutbound();
        $email->setMailerForSystem();

        if(!$email->Send()){
            $GLOBALS['log']->info("Could not send notification email: ". $email->ErrorInfo);
        }       
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in duplicating in before_save hook is very common. We want the logic hook to run just the first time. To make sure of that we can utilize a static variable called `$already_ran`.

```
class cases_email_notification
{
  static $already_ran = false;

  function send_notification($bean, $event, $arguments)
  {
        $GLOBALS['log']->info("send_notification start!"
        if(self::$already_ran == true) return;
        self::$already_ran = true;

        /*Get sugar email engine*/
        $email = new SugarPHPMailer();
        $email->setMailerForSystem();
        $email->From = 'it@gmail.com';
        $email->FromName ='SuiteCRM';
        /* Set Email Subject */
        $email->Subject=$subject;          
        $email->Body = ''; 
        $email->prepForOutbound();
        /* Send email to Production Department */
        $email->addAddress('admin@gmail.com');

        if(!$email->Send()){
            $GLOBALS['log']->info("Could not send notification email: ". $email->ErrorInfo);
        } else {
            $GLOBALS['log']->info("I send notification email!!!"
        }
  }       
}
```

Comment: when I comment out this line $email->addAddress($rev_email); the email isn't sent

Comment: I undestand. When you write $email=createCaseEmail($email,$rev_email,'New Case Email Notification',$bean,$xtpl); you change the variable $email. 
There are [some](https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/SugarPHPMailer/Send/php-sugarphpmailer-send-method-examples.html) examples of sending mail.

Comment: Does this work when you use the contents of a function createCaseEmail instead of calling it?

Comment: createCaseEmail($email,$rev_email,'New Case Email Notification',$bean,$xtpl);   I've tried this but it is still duplicating

Comment: The same email with the case is sent twice

Comment: are you saying I should remove this line if(empty($bean->fetched_row['id'])){ and try if(true)

Comment: I tried the other way you suggested and email is still duplicating but only happen sometimes

Comment: XTemplate usually use with *.tpl. Do it send twice when we delete all template string(see answer) ?

Comment: See the second example [here](https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/SugarPHPMailer/Send/php-sugarphpmailer-send-method-examples.html). from_html use in altBody property.

Comment: yes it does send it twice I'm thinking that the logic hook that I used to call it is being called twice. This is the logic hook $hook_array['before_save'][] = Array(2, 'Send Notification', 'custom/Extension/modules/Cases/Ext/cases_email_notification.php','cases_email_notification', 'send_notification');

Comment: Try to add record to log in your function(see code). If it add twice, problem is in the logic hook

Comment: I'm getting the error twice..so what in  the logic hook could be causing this

Comment: Try to add a check as I wrote above

Comment: Thanks for your help even that was giving me a little issue I managed to got it working with the help your answer